# Wordpress - Using custom fields to call relevant NivoSlider

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently looking to use a different NivoSlider on each post outside of the post content area, so I set up a custom field ('nivo_number') where I can enter the Nivo Slider number and call it within the template using

So, currently I have:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode;?>("<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nivo_number', true); ?>")<?php ; ?>
```

However this just outputs the following text on the site

do_shortcode("[nivoslider id='123']")

Can anyone help? If it doesn't make sense I will try and explain futher.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think the second `echo` is not necessary, I don't know if that is the problem, why don't you try:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nivo_number', true)); ?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $nivo_number = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nivo_number', true);
    echo do_shortcode($nivo_number);
?>
```

BTW what's exactly the value of the custom field? is it `[nivoslider id='123']` or just **123**?

Just noticed an error in your syntax. Here `echo do_shortcode;?>("<?php echo` you're closing `?>` before `(`, that might be the reason the code isn't interpreted.